# Add ToolTip to disabled Menu in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, menu

Is there a way to add ToolTip to disabled menu items in UWP?

I tried to add event like `Page_PointerMoved`. Unfortunately I can not find the right menu Item

Comment: For now, the Tooltip would not show for the disabled control. You could submit a **Feature Request** on [WPDev UserVoice](http://wpdev.uservoice.com/).

Comment: https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/37385026-show-tooltip-for-the-disabled-control-in-uwp